# How do we compare two files at two different location.One location is in winscp and another location is in git

Tags: git, winscp

i need to write a script to compare two files at two different location.One location is in winscp and another location is in git.say at location A is in winscp and it has 1000 files and location B is in git and it have some 1500 files.Now i need to write a script to check what all files are in common or different at both location.

Comment: just use `diff` or compare hashes

Comment: will it compare from winscp?

Comment: i want the files of location A to be compared to files from location B and then ge the output of similar files

Comment: Can you access both repositories from a single location, like a workstation or laptop? Then copy the winscp files there, git pull the files there, and use diff or a checksum mechanism to compare.

Comment: There's nothing like "winscp location". You probably mean SFTP or FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gist of what you should do:

1. generate hash lists per repo, i.g., `find repo_dir -type f -exec md5 {} + > hashes.txt`:

   ```
   MD5 (file_a) = 6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4
   MD5 (file_b) = 6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4
   ```

   *modify `find` as you need to include/exclude files*

   Consider each hash list as a key/value pair. You want to find the deltas across repos. You're only interested in repos that have the same files. You'll need a way to track this (like a `repoCount` counter).

   Each hash list data needs to go into another table table, indexing the files and pushing their hashes to the running table's entry.
2. Iterating the key/value table, if the entry exists in all repos, check the hashes to see if/where they differ, output accordingly as desired.

The data-structure could resemble this JSON:

```
{
    "file_path": { "repoCount": 3, "hashes": [ { "base": "repo1", "hash": "6f59..." }, ...],
    ...
}
```